# Django 1.8 throws an error: django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django

There is no perfect explanation for this question, can any one please explain why this error is getting raised

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/project-root/DjangoWebProject5/app/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from app.models import *
  File "/home/ubuntu/project-root/DjangoWebProject5/app/models.py", line 11, in <module>
    class Document(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet
```

**Edit 1**
**settings.py** INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'app',
    'app.views',
    #'bootstrap3_datetime',
    'djcelery',
    'kombu.transport.django',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Project Structure:

```
    Djangowebproject
                 -->Djangowebproject-->settings.py
                                    -->urls.py
                                    -->wsgi.py
                                    -->__init__.py
                 -->app-->migrations
                       -->static
                       -->templates
                       -->templatetags
                       -->admin.py
                       -->forms.py
                       -->models.py
                       -->urls.py
                       -->views.py
```

app/models.py is like

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

import datetime


class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')  # title of the post
    news = models.TextField(default='')  # body of the news
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%d/%m/%Y', default='')  # image file included in it
    link = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')  # video file url if present
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField("Date", default=datetime.datetime.now())  # this is date of scrapping
    approvedflag = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='-1')  # approved or not -1 for not and 1 for approved
    publishedfrom = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')  # this includes domain of page eg: twitter, greatandhra
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='direct post')  # published author for future use
    approvedby = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')   # user name of the approved person
    parse_objectid = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')   # unique id response
    source = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')   # page/post link


class fb_pages_sync(models.Model):
    pagename = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    sync_flag = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='-1')
    status_run = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='-1')
    src_pages = models.CharField(max_length=2,
                                 default='f')  # flag bit to know about whether the pages are form facebook or twitter
    verfied = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='-1')


class Poll(models.Model):
    """A poll object for use in the application views and repository."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def total_votes(self):
        """Calculates the total number of votes for this poll."""
        return self.choice_set.aggregate(Sum('votes'))['votes__sum']

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of a poll."""
        return self.text


class Choice(models.Model):
    """A poll choice object for use in the application views and repository."""
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def votes_percentage(self):
        """Calculates the percentage of votes for this choice."""
        total = self.poll.total_votes()
        return self.votes / float(total) * 100 if total > 0 else 0

    def __unicode__(self):
        """Returns a string representation of a choice."""
        return self.text
```

Comment: Not without seeing your code! The issue is likely to be in your `AppConfig` if you have one, otherwise something you have put in `settings.py`.

Comment: As @solarissmoke says, please provide us the info of you app structure and also `settings.py`

Comment: Thanks for editing@ruddra

Comment: As others have suggested before me , you need to show code. app/models.py ought to look interesting.

Comment: i have added app/models.py @e4c5

Comment: This is puzzling. Can't spot anything unusual in your models. Change this line in your views `from app.models import *` to be individual imports and try again. Don't use import *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed app should contain only the django apps that you want to include in your application, i see you have added app and app.views. views is not an app, it's a python file present in the app directory please remove that and try to migrate.

Also please add you custom apps after django's default apps for best practice.

Comment: i'm using celery, so to detect the tasks present in views.py in have introduced _app.views_ in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: @binayr is right about this, app.views isn't an app, so it really shouldn't be there. Not quire sure how that ties in with celery in your case

Comment: @VenkatRamana You do not need to include views in installed apps. as djcelery is already there. Once you run the celery server connect your celery task you the view you are trying to execute. for best practise put all your tasks in a separate file named as task.py in the same app directory.